# First record for each for every day only

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to find the first record for daily for each user. Each person has multi records for each day. I just want to see the first record for each person. Query is currently looking like this.[image: Current Query]

I need the query to look like this.
[image: NewQuery]

The code that i am currently using is:

```
SELECT acc_monitor_log.pin, USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]) AS DateValue, TimeValue([Time]) AS TimeValue, acc_monitor_log.device_name
FROM acc_monitor_log INNER JOIN USERINFO ON acc_monitor_log.pin = USERINFO.Badgenumber
WHERE (((acc_monitor_log.device_name)="IN"))
ORDER BY DateValue([Time]), TimeValue([Time]);
```

Please can anyone please point me in the right direction. I have change the Query Name to FirstClockIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first timevalue per person, you can achieve that easily by wrapping things in either `Min` or `First`, and grouping by the columns you want every row:

```
SELECT USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]) AS DateValue, Min(TimeValue([Time])) AS TimeValue, acc_monitor_log.device_name
FROM acc_monitor_log INNER JOIN USERINFO ON acc_monitor_log.pin = USERINFO.Badgenumber
WHERE (((acc_monitor_log.device_name)="IN"))
GROUP BY USERINFO.name, DateValue([Time]), acc_monitor_log.device_name
ORDER BY DateValue([Time]), Min(TimeValue([Time]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have Complied First clock and and last clock in based and min and max. Now the only thing i need to work on is that if the person didn't check in but they checked out how can i lave a bank space instead of all records moving up one space.

Comment: Eh... That's a separate and kind of broad question.You could start with a query selecting everyone who checked out, and left join to that. But it depends on your exact setup. Usually, I start with a table with everyone (perhaps that _USERINFO_ table), and use outer joins from there to select data. Then I filter out the unwanted data in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause.